# Python CGI - Script outputs source of generated page

Tags: python, html, apache, cgi

I have a CGI script that I wrote in python to use as the home page of the website I am creating. Everything works properly except when you view the page instead of seeing the page that it outputs you see the source code of the page, why is this? I dont mean that it shows me the source code of the .py file, it shows me all the `print`ed information as if I were looking at a .htm file in notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Content Type is text, and if you forgot to send the appropriate header in your CGI file, you will end up with what you are seeing.

Comment: I had this line `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />` in the code that I thought took care of that but i guess not... I added `print "Content-type: text/html"` to the beginning of the script and it works now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following before you print anything

print "Content-type: text/html"

Probably your script is not getting executed.
Is your python script executable?
Check whether you have the script under cgi-bin directory.